# Passing argument to system() in C

Tags: c, shell

I want to find the number of context switches of a program. I know there is a file `/proc/PID/status` which reports the number of context switches continuously while the program is running. However, after the process is finished that file is deleted, so I am not able to check the content.

For this reason, in the following C code, I am trying to copying that file before and after the region of interest.

```
int pid_num = getpid();
system("sudo cp /proc/$pid_num/status start.txt");
// do
system("sudo cp /proc/$pid_num/status finish.txt");
```

As I run the program, I get this message

```
 cp: cannot stat '/proc//status': No such file or directory
```

It seems that `$pid_num` in the system function is not correct. What is the correct form then?

Comment: C is not like a shell, you can't "expand" variables like you can in a shell (which, quite honestly, should have been taught by any decent book, tutorial or class). Instead, how about `snprintf` to create the string with whatever values you need?

Comment: Also, there are `GNU glib` extension `envz_add()`, but that's a long route.

Answer (score 2):

`C` uses format specifiers equivalent to more generic `$var` shell counterpart. You need to prepare the command-string before invoking `system()` call.

```c
#define START_FILE "start.txt"
#define END_FILE "finish.txt"
#define MAX_CMD_BUFFSIZE 256 // adjust as necessary

char cmdbuf[MAX_CMD_BUFFSIZE];

pid_t pid_num = getpid();
snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "sudo cp -f /proc/%d/status %s", pid_num, START_FILE);
int cmd_status = system(cmdbuf);
// verify 

snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "sudo cp -f /proc/%d/status %s", pid_num, END_FILE);
cmd_status = system(cmdbuf);
// verify
```

- use `-f` command option to replace target file if it already exists.
- Also, you need to run this program with an user with `sudo` privileges; which is inviting trouble. If process `status` file is available for every user for reading, check if you can drop `sudo` from command.